# Direct manipulation of C call stack

Tags: c, stack, call

Is it possible to directly access the call stack in C?

For example, could I do something like

```
pushInt(5);
pushInt(6);
printf("%d %d\n");
```

Although the paramaters (5 and 6) are not in the printf call, in theory I have pushed them on the stack.

Is this kind of trickery available? Is it portable?

Comment: that's the most portable way to do useful things ;)

Comment: Notice also that on many architectures arguments are partially passed in registers, so there is no stack you could modify...

Comment: @Mahkoe `Is this kind of trickery available?` of course it is. Use inline assembly. You can do any trick you want. Is it portable - I think you should answer yourself if you consider it portable

Comment: *C call stack* is a non term!